# Tinymce jQueryUI Dialog in Dialog input not clickable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, tinymce

I used this code for tinymce:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "#description",
    theme: "modern",
    mode: "exact",
    width: 840,
    height: 250,
    plugins: [
         "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
         "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
         "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor"
   ],
   content_css: "",
   toolbar1: "undo redo | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | styleselect",
   toolbar2: "| responsivefilemanager | link unlink anchor | image media | forecolor backcolor  | print preview code ",
    image_advtab: true ,
   //toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | l      ink image | preview media fullpage | forecolor backcolor emoticons", 
   external_filemanager_path:"/filemanager/",
   filemanager_title:"Responsive Filemanager" ,
   external_plugins: { "filemanager" : "/filemanager/plugin.min.js"},
   menubar:"",
   relative_urls: false,
   remove_script_host: false,
   style_formats: [
        {title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b'},
        {title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
        {title: 'Red header', block: 'h1', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
        {title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1'},
        {title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2'},
        {title: 'Table styles'},
        {title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1'}
    ],
   setup: function (ed) {
        ed.on("change", function () {
            TinyMceValid(ed);
        })
   }
});

function TinyMceValid(inst) {
    tinyMCE.triggerSave();
    $("#" + inst.id).valid();  
}
```

And Use this code for this problem But it's not working for me

```
jQuery(function ($) {      
   $.widget("ui.dialog", $.ui.dialog, {
  _allowInteraction: function(event) {
  return !!$(event.target).closest(".mce-container").length || this._super( event );
    }
  });
});
```

I have also used this solution:

```
$(document).on('focusin', function(e) {
  if ($(event.target).closest(".mce-window").length) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
 }
});
```

This solution is working on localhost but not on live server so please provide any solution for this problem to work on live server.

Comment: Have you read the jQuery bug report [Dialog: Allow registering elements outside a dialog for use when a modal dialog is open](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9087)? Amongst the comments are several suggestions for how to phrase the `_allowInteraction` callback including, at Comment 24, the one you have tried. You might like to try one of the other versions, eg those at Comment 38 or Comment 40. (you will need to change the selectors from cke... to mce...).

Comment: ... or simply check that your localhost/live jQuery versions are the same.